# Why does Maple plot a different result for a 3D parametric circle for parameter t from -100 to 100 vs 0 to 2$\pi$?

Tags: maple

I have the following parametric equation in three dimensions: $$\vec{r}(t) = (\cos t) \vec{i} + (\sin t) \vec{j}$$

I believe this is the equation for a circle on the xy-plane, centered at 0, with radius 1.

In Maple, if I plot this equation for values of t from 0 to $2\pi$ it looks fine.
[image: 0 to 2*Pi]

If I plot for t from -100 to 100, it does not look fine:
[image: -100 to 100]

Also note $0 to 8\pi$
[image: 0 to 8*Pi]

What is happening here?

Here are the commands in Maple:

```
with(VectorCalculus)
ihat := <1, 0, 0>
jhat := <0, 1, 0>
r := cos(t)*ihat + sin(t)*jhat
plot3d(r, t = -100 .. 100)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer by heropup is correct in the sense that, yes, the ranges t=-100..100 will overlap many times. That's because the period of r(t) is only 2*Pi.

The situation with t=0..8*Pi is similar, but with less overlap.

But it is not true that the `plot3d` command will choose the points according to some algorithm that relies on continuity and smoothness. Your r(t) is smooth and continuous. It is not true that it "*...chooses some points that it thinks are representative of the behavior of the curve*".

A more correct explanation is that there is no *adaptive* sampling algorithm at work here. Rather, the problem arises because the points are taken by a *uniform* splitting of the range into (default) 49 values for each of the two parameters. You have only one parameter, `t`, and the other is taken as some dummy.

It helps to visualize what's going on if we add a vertical z-component, to show the curve as a spiral.

```
restart:
with(VectorCalculus):
ihat := <1, 0, 0>:
jhat := <0, 1, 0>:
khat := <0, 0, 1>:
P:=plot3d(cos(t)*ihat + sin(t)*jhat + t*khat,
          t = 0..2*Pi,
          style=pointline, symbol=solidcircle, symbolsize=20,
          color=t, orientation=[-150,60,0], labels=[x,y,z]):
P;
```

[image]

The data points are stored in the plotting structure (assigned to `P` here) in a 49x49x3 Array. Here are the dimensions on that Array.

```
op(2,op([1,1],P));

      1 .. 49, 1 .. 49, 1 .. 3
```

Even here there is waste, as there are 49 duplicates x-y-z triples stored (because of the unseen dummy 2nd parameter which takes on 49 unused values) for *each* of the 49 t-values.

We could greatly reduce the storage by forcing the dummy 2nd parameter's resolution to be just `2`, the minimal allowed for the `plot3d` command. We get the same curve as before, but using far less storage, ie. roughly only 2/49 times the earlier storage.

```
plot3d(cos(t)*ihat + sin(t)*jhat + t*khat,
       t = 0..2*Pi, grid=[49,2],
       style=pointline, symbol=solidcircle, symbolsize=20,
       color=t, orientation=[-150,60,0], labels=[x,y,z]);
```

[image]

Here is the case for t=0..8*Pi. Since that has to split this wider t-range into the same default number of only 49 t-values the granularity of the t-resolution becomes more apparent.

```
plot3d(cos(t)*ihat + sin(t)*jhat + t*khat,
       t = 0..8*Pi,
       style=pointline, symbol=solidcircle, symbolsize=20,
       color=t, orientation=[-150,60,0], labels=[x,y,z]);
```

[image]

As user64494 mentions, you can correct for this (if you really insist on an unnecessarily wide t-range which entails overlapping) by specifying a larger resolution for the t-parameter. But you *really* should not also specify the resolution for the dummy second parameter as 600, as user64494 suggested in code. That would consume even more wasted storage. (As seen above, you can also save much wasted space by specifying the unseen dummy parameter's resolution to the minimal allowed which is 2.)

You could even get fancy in trying to guess-timate how many t-values might look ok...

```
G:=ceil((100+100+1)/(2*Pi))*49;

            G := 1568

plot3d(cos(t)*ihat + sin(t)*jhat, t = -100 .. 100,
       grid = [G, 2],
       labels=[x,y,z], orientation=[90,0,-180]);
```

[image]

Even this involves twice as much storage as necessary, because of the dummy second parameter. The easiest way to further halve the storage is to use instead the `spacecurve` command, which uses only one parameter (ie. no dummy 2nd parameter at all). Eg,

```
PS:=plots:-spacecurve(cos(t)*ihat + sin(t)*jhat,
                      t = 0..2*Pi,
                      color=black, orientation=[-150,60,0],
                      labels=[x,y,z]);
```

[image]

That uses 200 t-values by default. The Array which stores the data has one less dimension.

```
op(2,op([1,1],PS));

        1 .. 200, 1 .. 3
```

And you can raise that (if for some reason you insist on a range much wider than the period). Eg, with another guess-timate,

```
plots:-spacecurve(cos(t)*ihat + sin(t)*jhat,
                  t = -100..100, numpoints=ceil((100+100+1)/(2*Pi))*49,
                  color=black, orientation=[-150,60,0],
                  labels=[x,y,z]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a sampling artifact.

When you say $t = -100$ to $100$, you are specifying a range of $200$ radians for Maple to plot.  This corresponds roughly to about $32$ full rotations around the circle ($\frac{200}{2\pi} \approx 31.8$).  So you are overlapping the same path many times.

Since Maple is using an internal algorithm to decide how many points along this path to sample for plotting the curve, it sees this large range and chooses some points that it thinks are representative of the behavior of the curve.  It can't choose *every* point along the path because there are infinitely many.  So it picks and then connects them with lines because it assumes that the behavior of the curve is roughly linear between the points it samples.  The result is this artifact.

There is usually a plotting option to increase the sampling resolution, basically telling Maple to sample more points so that the plot doesn't look so strange.  As long as the curve being plotted is "smooth" (i.e., continuous and differentiable), this usually produces good results even when the plotting range is very large.  As I am not an expert in Maple, preferring to use *Mathematica* instead, all I can tell you is that in *Mathematica*, this is specified using the option `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`.  The first one increases the number of points to sample, and the second tells the program how many times to recursively bisect between the sampled points if it detects that the plot is not smooth.  Increasing both of these will generally produce better results.

Answer (score 2):

The `grid` option helps:

```
with(VectorCalculus):Digits := 15:ihat := <1, 0, 0>:jhat := <0, 1, 0>:
r := cos(t)*ihat + sin(t)*jhat:plot3d(r, t = -100 .. 100, grid = [600, 600]);
```

[image]

Addition. The same issue in Mathematica

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], Cos[u], 1}, {u, -100, 100}]
```

[image]

and a similar workaround

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], Cos[u], 1}, {u, -100, 100}, PlotPoints -> 300]
```